# Angular form validation with catch value

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have a form and a `submit` button. Which is `disabled` until all the form `inputs` are valid.

Actually, the problem occurs when chrome catches the input values on loading the page. So, in fact, the fields aren’t empty and it means the form is valid and the submit button should be `enabled`. But it is not until you click at least once wherever  on the page body.

I think, it has a bad effect for users to see the submit button disabled while the form is filled so I am looking for a way to valid form by catch values too.

I used Plunker to show my code. Although, I can not show you the actual problem. I mean catch values in the fields but any help would be appreciated.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZqkhJqP8iSgehhNAe8If?p=preview)`

```
    <form
        ng-class="{true: 'animated'}[LoginAnimate]"
        class="form login stylenormal col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"
        name="x_form"
        action="j_security_check"
        method="post"
        novalidate
    >
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : x_form.j_username.$invalid}">
                <label>username:</label>
                <input
                    class="form-control"
                    maxlength="50"
                    name="j_username"
                    size="20"
                    type="text"
                    autofocus
                    ng-focus="userfocused = true"
                    ng-blur="userfocused = false"
                    ng-model="user.j_username"
                    required
                >
                <div data-icon="icon" ng-class="{true: 'input-toggle active', false: 'input-toggle'}[userfocused]" class="">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : x_form.j_password.$invalid}">
                <label>password:</label>
                <input
                    class="form-control"
                    maxlength="50"
                    name="j_password"
                    size="20"
                    type="password"
                    ng-focus="passfocused = true"
                    ng-blur="passfocused = false"
                    ng-model="user.j_password"
                    required
                >
                <div data-icon="icon" ng-class="{true: 'input-toggle active', false: 'input-toggle'}[passfocused]" class="">
                    <i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group submit-bar" ng-class="{true: 'loaded'}[SubmitLoad]">
                <input
                    class="btn"
                    type="submit"
                    ng-disabled="x_form.$invalid"
                    value="submit"
                >
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

I`

Comment: have you tried .. `ng-init`? like in your case inside `form` include `ng-init="user = user || {} "`

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your **Plunker** code. And filled form with default values. Then checked whether form is valid or not. It's valid even if you do not click on a page.

Here is a modified version of your [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/AhwGUEhwR1b5viEs0niO)

```
...
$scope.user = {
    j_password: '123',
    j_username: '12323'
}
...
```

Correct me if I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually my problem is about the users who use "remember username and password" offer in chrome, so when they launch the page they expect to see their login info in the form and don't need to type again. My form in this kind of situation can not valid the fields which are already filled by catch data.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a mistake of the browser chrome. Without using angulargs the same thing happens. Until click on the page, even `document.querySelector ('#LoginForm_password').value` has a blank `value`. You have to write in support of the browser chrome.